# Visual Studio 2013 does not update minified bootstrap.css

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013

In my ASP .NET MVC 5.1 application in `bootstrap.css` file in section:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dl-horizontal dt {
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: left;
    text-align: right;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .dl-horizontal dd {
    margin-left: 180px;
  }
```

I changed `width: 160px;` to `width: 260px;` and `margin-left: 180px;` to `margin-left: 280px;`.

I saved, reloaded, later restarted Visual Studio. In my website in Chrome I checked loaded styles:

```
.dl-horizontal dt {
float: left;
width: 160px; //STILL 160px !
overflow: hidden;
clear: left;
text-align: right;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

so I checked `bootstrap.min.css` via Visual Studio and I saw that changes I've made to the `bootstrap.css` are were not applied to `bootstrap.min.css` so I applied them manually to minified file and Chrome loaded them correctly.

How to make VS2013 update this minified file?

---

EDIT: I must say that before VS2013(today) did update `boostrap.min.css` after making changes in `boostrap.css`. It just didn't do it after these changes.

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace WebApplication2 {
    public class BundleConfig {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));

            // Set EnableOptimizations to false for debugging. For more information,
            // visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a style bundle to load the file?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am not sure. Styles from `bootstrap.min.css` are loaded into site, just this file isn't updated after changes in `boostrap.css`. Did you mean this: 
       `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")` and `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")` in `_Layout.csthml`?

Comment: Check if you have a style bundle in you `BundleConfig.cs` file that includes `bootstrap.css` (not `bootstrap.min.css`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke and `  BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);` in `Global.asax`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added edit with `BundleConfig.cs`.

Comment: That looks correct. You should remove `bootstrap.min.css` from your project and let the bundler do the work for you. In debug mode, it will include the `boostrap.css` in the view. In release mode, it will include a minified version. [This gives a good explanation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I deleted `min` version it was not regenerated afterwards. I run app in debug and release mode... once deleted it is gone.

Comment: The old min version may have been cached in your browser - try a refresh. A feature of bundling is that if you have just `boostrap.css`, it will use that in debug mode, but in release mode, the bundler creates an optimized version. If you make a change to `boostrap.css`,the next time the app runs, the bundler creates a new optimized version. However if you also have `bootstrap.min.css` it will use that file instead in release mode. These are 2 different files so making a change in one does not affect the other.

Answer (score 1):

min files are updated after a rebuild. Force a rebuild to update the min.css files. I would be curious if you deleted the bootstrap.min.css and then rebuilt the project.